# Cannot create album with same name as a deleted one on IOS?

Tags: ios, alassetslibrary

I use category [ALAssetsLibrary+CustomPhotoAlbum](https://github.com/Kjuly/ALAssetsLibrary-CustomPhotoAlbum) to save image into a custom name album.

I recently encounter this problem: if i have an album (ex: myAlbum) in library, after i deleted it `ALAssetsLibrary+CustomPhotoAlbum` unable to create an album with same name.

After debuging, i found out that the call to

```
[ALAssestLibrary addAssetsGroupAlbumWithName:resultBlock:failureBlock]
```

successfully return (the resultBlock was called). But the album is not created.

Anyone has same problem?

Comment: i have the exact same problem with iOS 8. Any luck?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26003211/assetslibrary-framework-broken-on-ios-8

Comment: haven't got any. Thanks for the links, did you give Photo Framework a shot?

Comment: no i didn't. I couldn't find any sample code of how to create one using new photo framework. though since its a bug with iOS 8 I doubt the results will be any different

Comment: Per apple's documentation, the Assets library has been practically depreciated. Use the photo framework. You'll also get more detailed reasons on why things don't work if they don't.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I know my answer is very late but in case anyone face the same problem like me. The problem appears with me in iOS 8.0 or later and the solution is to use **Photos.framework**. Use the updated category from [Github](https://github.com/Kjuly/ALAssetsLibrary-CustomPhotoAlbum) and please don't forget to import **Photos.framework**.